# Get session timeout from Coldfusion server in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, coldfusion, session-variables, http-status-codes

I have an application implemented in **Coldfusion** and  **AngularJS**.

I have ***an external authentication system*** used for the security of our applications. It's called in the file **application.cfc** of the application. When the user tries to access to the application, the authentication system is called and if the authentication is correct, the user can access to the application. I put in session some data about the users'roles.
This security system is defined with another url.

In views I have some forms with drop-down list populating thanks to *AJAX queries*.
As there is no refresh of the page (Single page application).
If the server session is out, the queries are not correctly executed: I obtain the server **status 302**, because the authentication tries to be launched and I can see in the colnsole:

```
Failed to load https://myAuthenticationSystem: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://myApplication' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I try to retrieve the status in my Angular JS script and I obtain the status 0 and data are null. Is it normal ??

I would like to fore the reload of the aaplication if the server session is out, for avoiding this kind of problem (ideally with a pop-up message in AngularJS "Session Expired. You are going redirected to the authentication..."). How can I do that?
Here my code:

**application.cfc**

```
<cfcomponent output="false" extends="RootApplication">

    <cfset this.name = "myApp"/>
    <cfset this.SessionManagement="yes"/>
    <cfset this.clientStorage="registry"/>
    <cfset this.clientManagement="yes"/>
    <cfset this.SetDomainCookies = false/>

    <cfset This.loginStorage="session">
    <cfset This.sessionTimeout=CreateTimeSpan(0,1,0,0)>
    <cfset This.applicationTimeout = CreateTimeSpan(0,0,2,0) >

    <cffunction name="OnApplicationStart" access="public" returntype="boolean" output="false" hint="Fires when the application is first created.">

        <cfreturn true />

    </cffunction>


    <cffunction name="onSessionStart">                  
        //  CALL THE AUTHENTICATION SYSTEM
        ..........................    
    </cffunction>

    <cffunction name="onRequestStart">

        // Check the user access
        ...........................

        // PUT DATA IN SESSION
        <cfset SESSION.userLogin = "#authenticationSystem.USERID#">
        <cfset SESSION.tocken = "#authenticationSystem.tocken#" />
        <cfset SESSION.userRoles = #userProfile.Roles#>

    </cffunction>   

</cfcomponent>
```

**index.cfm**

```
<cfheader name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" ng-app="ContactsApp" class="ng-app:ContactsApp" id="ng-app">
    <head>
        ............................
    </head>

    <body>

        // TRANSFORM THE COLDFUSION VARIABLES IN JS VARIABLES FOR ANGULAR JS    
        <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
            <cfoutput>
                var #toScript(SESSION.userLogin, "userLogin")#;
                var #toScript(SESSION.tocken, "tocken")#;
                var #toScript(SESSION.userRoles, "userRoles")#;
            </cfoutput>
        </script>

      <div>         
            <ng-view></ng-view>
      </div>

        ............................

    </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var app=angular.module('ContactsApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngDialog', 'angular-popover']);

// register the interceptor as a service
app.factory('HttpInterceptor', ['$q', '$rootScope', function($q, $rootScope) {
       return {
            // On request success
            request : function(config) {
                // Return the config or wrap it in a promise if blank.
                return config || $q.when(config);
            },

            // On request failure
            requestError : function(rejection) {
                //console.log(rejection); // Contains the data about the error on the request.  
                // Return the promise rejection.
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            },

            // On response success
            response : function(response) {
                //console.log(response); // Contains the data from the response.
                // Return the response or promise.
                return response || $q.when(response);
            },

            // On response failure
            responseError : function(rejection) {
                //console.log(rejection); // Contains the data about the error.
                //Check whether the intercept param is set in the config array. 
                //If the intercept param is missing or set to true, we display a modal containing the error
                if (typeof rejection.config.intercept === 'undefined' || rejection.config.intercept)
                {
                    //emitting an event to draw a modal using angular bootstrap
                    $rootScope.$emit('errorModal', rejection.data);
                }

                // Return the promise rejection.
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
        };
 }]);

app.config(function($routeProvider, $httpProvider, ngDialogProvider){
    $httpProvider.defaults.cache = false;
    if (!$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = {};
    }

    // disable IE ajax request caching
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['If-Modified-Since'] = '0';

    // Add the interceptor to the $httpProvider to intercept http calls
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('HttpInterceptor');


    $routeProvider.when('/all-contacts',
    {
      templateUrl: 'template/allContacts.html',
      controller: 'ctrlContacts',       
    })
    .when('/view-contacts/:contactId',
    {
      templateUrl: 'template/viewContact.html',
      controller: 'ctrlViewContacts'
    })  
    .otherwise({redirectTo:'/all-contacts'});  
});    

)

app.controller('ctrlContacts', function ($scope, $timeout, MyTextSearch, ContactService){

    // ACCESS TO THE JS VARIABLES
    $scope.userRoles =  userRoles;
    $scope.userLogin = userLogin;           

    ............

});


app.controller('ctrlViewContacts', function ($scope, $routeParams, MyTextSearch, ContactService, RequestService, ReportService){

    // ACCESS TO THE JS VARIABLES
    $scope.userRoles =  userRoles;
    $scope.userLogin = userLogin;       

    // EXECUTE AJAX QUERY
ContactService.loadCategory('undefined',0).success(function(categories, status, header, config){
    $scope.categories = categories;
    console.log("status:" + status);
})
.error(function (data, status, header, config) {
    console.log("sessionExpired: " + sessionExpired);
    console.log("ERROR ");
    console.log("data: " + data);
    console.log("status:" + status);
    console.log("header: " + header);
    console.log("config: " + config);
           if (status==302) {
                alert("Session expired - New Authentication requested");
                window.location.replace(headers('http://intragate.test.ec.europa.eu/remed'));
            }   
           if (status==0) {
                alert("ERROR 0 - Session expired - New Authentication requested");
                //$window.location.reload();
            }                   
}).finally(function() {
  console.log("finally finished repos");
}); 


});

.........................
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Sebastien

Comment: Application.cfc allows for an onSessionEnd() method.  That seems to be the simplest approach.

Comment: if the page is not refreshed, is the function will be lunched?

Comment: Does it matter that your Application Timeout -- CreateTimeSpan(0,0,2,0)   is Shorter then your Session Timeout --  CreateTimeSpan(0,1,0,0) ? (From what iv read this should have no effect but the document was CF-9)

Comment: "if the page is not refreshed, is the function will be lunched?" Yes, *but* it's called automatically in the background and is not tied to a specific user http request.